# Using aspnet_merge yields errors with .svc files

Tags: asp.net, merge, precompile

I'm precompiling all my websites and using the `aspnet_merge` tool to merge all the App_Web* dll files into one. The tool takes care of updating the corresponding `.compiled` file as well to point to the new merged assembly. BUT, for `.svc` files the `.compiled` file is not updated which gives me the following error at runtime

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_10iin0kr, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
```

If i open the `.compiled` file in notepad and replaces `App_Web_10iin0kr` with `Web` (which is the name of my merged dll file) everything works fine. Its a bit annoying since building and publishing is all automatic so i would have to write a script that did this as a post-build step. I haven't been able to find any documentation or people complaining about this, but before i start a new thread on MSDN i want to hear any of you guys if you've been running into the same problem as well and if there is a work around.

Comment: I have filed a bug at Microsoft Connect here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/619202/using-aspnet-merge-yields-errors-with-svc-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing here... guess its not being resolved, Microsoft is not responding at all so i just have to do post-merge processing :(